# Axios login request: Unauthorized, request status code 401

Tags: node.js, authentication, axios, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to get an authorization token by making a request to an api using axios:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://62.110.134.187/api/signin',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    auth: {
        username: usr,
        password: pwd
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error)
})
```

I'm getting always status code 401(Unauthorized):

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

Where I'm doing wrong?

The fact is that making the same request using python works fine:

```
payload = "username=%s&password=%s" % (usr,pwd)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response = requests.request("POST", url_login, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
data = response.json()
token = data["token"]
```

Comment: In python, you are sending data in body, while in case of axios, it is header (basic auth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sending username and password in `auth: {}` in axios, you are doing the basic-authentication, basically sending `Authorization: basic <base64(user:pass)>` header.

As per working python program, you need to send the username and password as part of the request body. You need to serialize the body params for url-encoded content type as well.

e.g.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://62.110.134.187/api/signin',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: querystring.stringify({
        username: usr,
        password: pwd
    })
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error)
})
```

Comment: updated the answer, you need to serialize the body as well.
https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs